# how to merge two list into a sorted list without using sort function?

Tags: python, sorting

```
def merge(L1, L2):
'''(list of int, list of int) -> (list of int)

Return a list of ints sorted in increasing order that is 
the merge of the given sorted lists of integers.

>>> merge([1, 2, 4], [3, 5])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

'''
new_lst = []
i = 0

while i < len(L1):
    for item in L2:
        if L1[i] < item:
            new_lst.append(L1[i])
            new_lst.insert(i + 1, item)
            i += 1

return new_lst
```

here is what I do, however when I run the example, it shows

```
merge([1, 2, 4], [3, 5])
[1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 4]
```

I want to know what's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show any attempt you have made and explain what difficulties you are having? StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You have to show your coding attempt in the form of a [MCVE].

Comment: Hint: the input lists are already sorted. Use this fact!

Comment: then you need to implement your own [Sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Comment: @TedHopp that is not guaranty

Comment: @Copperfield - It is according to the comments in OP's code.

Comment: You are just lacking the case, where two consecutive elements in `L1` or `L2` are smaller then the corresponding one in the other list. Just put the second insert in an `else` part.

Comment: And you will have to change your loops slightly.

Comment: what should I write inside the insert? could you explain more detail? thx!

Comment: One way to approach this type of problem is to get a deck of cards and build some small lists. Then, write down each step you take to make a new, sorted, list from them. Then you should be able to write a program to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate through one entire list for each element of the other list. Instead, your basic operation should be to look at the current element from each list and append the smaller one to the new list. Keep doing this until you run out of elements in one of the lists and then append all the remaining elements from the other list.

Your question reads like a class assignment, so I don't want to just post the code. However, here's an outline. You will need two index counters, one for each list. Your `while` loop should iterate while both counters are shorter than their corresponding list lengths (e.g., `while i < len(L1) and j < len(L2):`). When the loop exits, one of the counters will still be shorter than its corresponding list, so just run a second loop to append all the remaining elements.